# trying to port container to ARM

Tags: docker, mono, arm, dockerfile

Im trying to port the following [container](https://github.com/dmitryint/docker-duplicati/blob/master/Dockerfile) to ARM.
so i did the following

I downloaded the `Dockerfile` and the `entrypoint.sh` then i replaced the first line in `Dockerfile` with `FROM arm32v7/mono:4.8` and built it successfully.

but when i try to use the finished image i get the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

Does this mean that it does not find the `entrypoint.sh` or something that it does not find something that `entrypoint.sh` tries to start?

Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: Have to look at this https://forums.docker.com/t/standard-init-linux-go-175-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file/20025/3

Comment: @GauravPathak that worked please post it with some more content as a answer and ill accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec user process caused "no such file or directory"`

Linux/Unix Shell generally throws this error when either the file is not present physically at that location or if the file format is not in compliance to that of Linux/Unix.

There is a workaround for this situation on the [docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/standard-init-linux-go-175-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file/20025).

You can try changing the file format from DOS to UNIX, all you need is `dos2unix` tool installed.

Use `dos2unix entrypoint.sh` and also change the permission to make it `-rwx-` for everyone.